# Why android binder need mmap?

Tags: android, android-binder

Binder client and server use binder driver to send and receive data. By reading binder related source code, I find that APP process send and receive data by ioctl(BINDER_READ_WRITE), and binder driver read data by copy_from_user and write data by copy_to_user.

Since binder driver implements a character device and send/recv data by ioctl(BINDER_READ_WRITE), then why binder need mmap? After mmap, APP process can read/write data from/to the mmap-ed shared memory, ioctl(BINDER_READ_WRITE) is not necessary.

My question is why binder dose not use mmap-ed shared memory to send/recv data, but using ioctl(BINDER_READ_WRITE)?

It seems the only job mmap does is to alloc memory buffer. If it is like this, when it can alloc memory buffer in binder_open, then binder_mmap is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems the only job mmap does is to alloc memory buffer. If it is like this, when it can alloc memory buffer in binder_open, then binder_mmap is not needed.

`mmap` is needed here, as the point is not just to allocate a buffer for the kernel, but to allocate some memory shared by the userspace program and the kernel. The kernel also needs to verify in `mmap` that this region is read-only and cannot be made writable with `mprotect`.

> Since binder driver implements a character device and send/recv data by ioctl(BINDER_READ_WRITE), then why binder need mmap? After mmap, APP process can read/write data from/to the mmap-ed shared memory, ioctl(BINDER_READ_WRITE) is not necessary.

The `mmap` region is read-only by userspace, the app cannot write to it. This will make more sense if we go over how it transaction works and what this buffer is actually used for.

A userspace program first opens `/dev/binder` and calls `mmap` to map this read-only memory. Then a transaction is initiated with the `BINDER_WRITE_READ` `ioctl` command. The data for this command is as follows:

```c
struct binder_write_read {
    binder_size_t       write_size; /* bytes to write */
    binder_size_t       write_consumed; /* bytes consumed by driver */
    binder_uintptr_t    write_buffer;
    binder_size_t       read_size;  /* bytes to read */
    binder_size_t       read_consumed;  /* bytes consumed by driver */
    binder_uintptr_t    read_buffer;
};
```

This gets handled by `binder_thread_write`:

```c
struct binder_write_read bwr;
// ...
binder_thread_write(proc, thread, bwr.write_buffer, bwr.write_size, &bwr.write_consumed);
```

You can see that the `write_buffer` is actually a userspace buffer:

```c
static int binder_thread_write(struct binder_proc *proc,
            struct binder_thread *thread,
            binder_uintptr_t binder_buffer, size_t size,
            binder_size_t *consumed)
{
    uint32_t cmd;
    struct binder_context *context = proc->context;
    void __user *buffer = (void __user *)(uintptr_t)binder_buffer;
```

This is the same for the `read_buffer`. These two buffers are **not** related to the buffer that was previously mmaped.

The `write_buffer` is used for sending commands (not the same as `ioctl` commands) to the binder driver, and the `read_buffer` is for receiving responses from the driver. One of these commands is `BC_TRANSACTION`, which gets handled in the `binder_transaction` function. The argument of the `BC_TRANSACTION` command is located right after the command in the `write_buffer`, and it has the following structure:

```c
struct binder_transaction_data {
    /* The first two are only used for bcTRANSACTION and brTRANSACTION,
     * identifying the target and contents of the transaction.
     */
    union {
        /* target descriptor of command transaction */
        __u32   handle;
        /* target descriptor of return transaction */
        binder_uintptr_t ptr;
    } target;
    binder_uintptr_t    cookie; /* target object cookie */
    __u32       code;       /* transaction command */

    /* General information about the transaction. */
    __u32           flags;
    pid_t       sender_pid;
    uid_t       sender_euid;
    binder_size_t   data_size;  /* number of bytes of data */
    binder_size_t   offsets_size;   /* number of bytes of offsets */

    /* If this transaction is inline, the data immediately
     * follows here; otherwise, it ends with a pointer to
     * the data buffer.
     */
    union {
        struct {
            /* transaction data */
            binder_uintptr_t    buffer;
            /* offsets from buffer to flat_binder_object structs */
            binder_uintptr_t    offsets;
        } ptr;
        __u8    buf[8];
    } data;
};
```

Looking at `binder_transaction`, we can see that this structure contains more userspace pointers:

```c
const void __user *user_buffer = (const void __user *)(uintptr_t)tr->data.ptr.buffer;
```

This is also true for `tr->data.ptr.offsets`. These buffers are still not the region that was mmaped.

Inside `binder_transaction`, we see calls to `binder_alloc_new_buf`. This is where that mmaped region is first used. In the remainder of the function, `tr->data.ptr.buffer` and `tr->data.ptr.offsets` will be "translated" into a form usable by the receiving/target process (for example, if we're sending a file descriptor, we need to translate that into a new file descriptor in the receiving process). The translated results are then copied to the target's mmaped region with `binder_alloc_copy_to_buffer`.

```c
switch (hdr->type) {
    case BINDER_TYPE_BINDER:
    case BINDER_TYPE_WEAK_BINDER: {
        struct flat_binder_object *fp;

        fp = to_flat_binder_object(hdr);
        ret = binder_translate_binder(fp, t, thread);

        if (ret < 0 ||
            binder_alloc_copy_to_buffer(&target_proc->alloc, t->buffer, object_offset, fp, sizeof(*fp))) {
            // ...
        }
    } break;
    case BINDER_TYPE_HANDLE:
    case BINDER_TYPE_WEAK_HANDLE: {
        struct flat_binder_object *fp;

        fp = to_flat_binder_object(hdr);
        ret = binder_translate_handle(fp, t, thread);
        if (ret < 0 ||
            binder_alloc_copy_to_buffer(&target_proc->alloc, t->buffer, object_offset, fp, sizeof(*fp))) {
            // ...
        }
    } break;

    case BINDER_TYPE_FD: {
        struct binder_fd_object *fp = to_binder_fd_object(hdr);
        binder_size_t fd_offset = object_offset +
            (uintptr_t)&fp->fd - (uintptr_t)fp;
        int ret = binder_translate_fd(fp->fd, fd_offset, t, thread, in_reply_to);

        fp->pad_binder = 0;
        if (ret < 0 ||
            binder_alloc_copy_to_buffer(&target_proc->alloc, t->buffer, object_offset, fp, sizeof(*fp))) {
            // ...
        }
    } break;
    ...
```

The sending process's `mmap` region is not used when sending a transaction. It will only be used when receiving a transaction.

Hopefully it's clear now why `ioctl` can't be used.